# Geodes that float in the ocean?

Tags: geology, geode

What would happen if you threw a geode into the ocean. Would it sink down to a certain altitude based on how hollow the geode is or would it float on top or sink to the bottom?

And could geodes form in the ocean and then break loose and be released into the ocean? Do geodes in the ocean exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it sink down to a certain altitude based on how hollow the geode
> is or would it float on top or sink to the bottom?

Most geodes are made of quartz or calcite. Their densities are somewhere between 2.6 and 2.7 g/cm<sup>3</sup>. Let's round it up to 3 for simplicity. This is three times the density of water.

So, for a geode to float it needs to be at least two thirds empty volume.

But! This is assuming what's inside is air. Geodes form from various fluids or gases. When they formed, if they had a fluid inside, and it is no longer inside, then the geode is not hermetically sealed. This means that once you drop it in the ocean, water will start leaking inside and it will eventually sink. If the geode formed from gas, and it is sealed, then yes there is a chance it will keep on floating.

> And could geodes form in the ocean and then break loose and be
> released into the ocean?

No, because if they form in the ocean, they have seawater inside. Not air. So their density cannot be lower than that of seawater, and they cannot float.

Answer (score 1):

In order to equilibrate a geode with the ocean, there must be a location where the density of the water matches that of the geode including the latter's enclosed empty space. But water in the oceans is very near to an incompressible fluid; its density varies only over a very narrow range. Thus if a geode (or a sinking ship) is dense enough to sink at all from the top of the ocean, in all likelihood it remain dense enough to go all the way to the bottom.